# Arrays and combining [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, merge

```
<?php
$ReturnValue = array();

if ($handle = opendir('img/albums/brinquedos/')){
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))){
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".."){   
            $ReturnValue[] .= $entry;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

foreach($ReturnValue as $row){
    echo '<div class="galleryItem"><img src=img/albums/brinquedos/'.$row.'><h2 class="marketing menuItem">Hey</h2></div>';
}?>
```

So this is a script for fetching all the images in a folder and throwing them to a page, problem is:

It gets all the images and throws them at once so I'm not sure how to add an image description to each image...

would `array_combine()` do the trick? Or not, because an associative array would have its index replaced with the key `?` as:

```
$randomArray = array("a"=>"b","c"=>"d")

$randomArray[a] ?
```

Despite being a possibly stupid question it is still interesting.

Comment: What do you mean? 'It gets all the images and throws them at once '

Comment: If you found the solution on your own, can you please post it here as an answer, Q&A style, for the benefit of the community?

Comment: It gets all the images thrown at once... But each image needs a description and I'm not sure if associative arrays would work. perhaps I could append another list with the description of each image using jQuery .. suggestions ?

Perhaps $array[0] would be the equivalent of saying " The index 0 contains an image ( key ) that has a description ( value )" would be precise ??

Comment: Where are you planning to store these descriptions? You could have a $row['description']

Comment: on another array and array_combine($imgArray,$descriptionArray) them. You think that would work ?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a key ?

Comment: Do you have your images descriptions in another array?

Comment: yes ! all the descriptions are in another array but internally would an array made of images accept values ?

Comment: I dont get it. Use multi-dimensional array. $array[0]['image']= 'imagePath';$array[0]['description'] = 'Hey';

Comment: because the images are already being fetched by another "array-maker"